# Vectorising convolution operation on a vector processor

Tags: c, vector, vectorization, simd, convolution

Background: I am trying to convolve a signal of 512 elements with a filter of length = 36 elements(or coefficients) and this operation needs to be performed on a vector processor(512 bit SIMD). Below is the pseudo code:

```
for(i = 0; i < RBs ; i++)                // Over Resource Blocks
{
    for(j = 0; j < (IFFT_Len + Fil_Len -1); j++)        ​// Over Output Length
    {
        acc = 0;

        for(k = 0; k < Fil_Len; k++)   // over conv operation
        {
            acc += Filter[k + (i * fil_data)] * IFFT[j - k + (i * ifft_data)];

        }

        x[j] = acc;
    }

   UFMC_sig += x;
}
```

Output of conv. operation = len(A) + len(B) - 1

I have 16 bit data inputs (IFFT and Filter values) which means for the operation I have a vector len of 16 complex valued elements(512/16(complex) = 16). I have to try to vectorise the loops.

1. If I vectorise loop "k", then it will always pull vec_len data from the two variables which is not needed for every iteration, e.g with j = 0; to fill the 0th value in the output X as x[0], I only need 0th element from both Fil and IFFT variable. However on vectorising it, it will pull vec_len of data from Fil (vec_len of "k" indices), and  vec_len of data with indices subtracted from j(which is 0 in 1st itr) and would fetch negative indices for IFFT and that would result in error.
2. If I vectorise loop "j", then x[j] will have to wait till all iterations of "k" are complete. Then how do I schedule that.
3. Another issue being The Filter length(36 elements) and the output len(547 elements) is not divisible by 16( not perfect vectorisation). Would this mean that it cannot be vectorised.

I am not sure how to resolve this problem.

P.S: This is implemented with C

Comment: Which vector processor specifically?  Are you using AVX512?  What types are your arrays?  signed or unsigned 16-bit integer?  You're storing the complex values as separate arrays of real and imaginary part, right?

Comment: Synopsys ASIP - cdsp 2017
I have complex cq15 signed arrays("16 bit complex" - 32 bit real valued) which store real and imag values together.

Comment: 3. you might need a cleanup loop to handle the last few elements but most of the work can hopefully vectorized.  Sometimes you can do an unaligned final vector that ends at the end of your array, but here you'd need some kind of masking or shift to avoid double-counting the overlap elements.  Scalar cleanup is simple but low-performance.